# How do I create single-use buttons in python turtle?

Tags: python, button, menu, python-turtle

I am currently trying to create a multiple-choice menu in python using Turtle.
I have been able to create a button (more a clickable area) which, when clicked, erases whats on the screen then writes a new menu with new choices.

```py
turtle.onscreenclick(btnclick,1)
turtle.listen()
```

`btnclick()` being the function which states the coordinates and what happens when clicked.

```py
def btnclick(x,y):
    if x > -300 and x < -190 and y > -50 and y < -20:
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("hello4", True, align="center")
```

The problem is, when this new menu shows up, the old clickable areas are still active. How do I reset all parameters in order to be able to create new buttons each time the screen is cleared ?

PS: I tried `turtle.clear()`, `turtle.reset()` or `turtle.resetscreen()`, without any success.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the current button handler once you determine it's a hit:

```
def btnclick(x, y):
    if -300 < x < -190 and -50 < y < -20:
        turtle.onscreenclick(None, 1)
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("hello4", move=True, align="center")
```

And then enable a different button handler for the modified menu.